# Ignore skip/take in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

There are few big stored procedures in database.
There are @skip and @take parameters.
Can I use this stored procedure and disable @take? I want select all rows sometimes but sometimes @take rows. Can I use something like 'if else' for disabling @take, (if @take is null - for example) and not duplicate main select code or not duplicate this stored procedures without @skip,@take?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
@Skip INT,
@Take INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT col1, col2, ...
...
...
...
 FROM ...
 WHERE ... 
 ORDER BY ....

OFFSET @Skip ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY
```

I want to achieve something like this (@skip, @take only when it is passed):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
@Skip INT = null,
@Take INT = null
AS
BEGIN
SELECT col1, col2, ...
...
...
...
 FROM ...
 WHERE ... 
 ORDER BY ....
if (@skip IS NOT NULL AND @take IS NOT NULL)
    OFFSET @Skip ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accept default `NULL` values and set `@Skip` and `@Take` to 0 and very big value when parameters are omitted.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE YourProcedure
    @Skip INT = NULL,
    @Take INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Skip IS NULL
        SET @Skip = 0

    IF @Take IS NULL
        SET @Take = 999999999

    SELECT
        YourColumn
    FROM
        YourTable
    ORDER BY
        SomeColumn
    OFFSET 
        @Skip ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 
        @Take ROWS ONLY 

END
```

Make sure that your max `@Take` value is always greater than your query result rows.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought to do the same way, maybe I will, but can I do without SET @Take = 999999999?

Comment: An alternative to avoid using Skip and Take is to write your query with dynamic SQL and optionally adding the `OFFSET/FETCH clause`.