# Is it possible to page through data using a view?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I currently have a view which returns all together 80K + records. What I would like to accomplish is a means of paging through these records 60 rows at a time. The current code I have on SQL is in a view. My question is, is it possible to page through these records 60 records at a time using my view?

The View

```sql
SELECT         o.ID, o.Name, o.DateRan, s.Name AS Job, o.Start, o.[End], o.Status, o.Logs 
FROM            dbo.output AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                         dbo.jobs AS j ON o.Job = j.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.scripts AS s ON  j.Script = s.ID 
Where o.DateRan < GETDATE()

ORDER BY o.ID DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 60 ROWS ONLY
```

The call in c# using DB context.

```cs
_output = new Entities();
_output.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
_output.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var _ot = await _output.dashboardview.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ID).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The expected result is to be able to successfully page through the results from the view.

Comment: You need a parameter for `offset` so it should be a `stored procedure`. In LINQ you can use `Take(60)`

Comment: It's not different than paging while reading from a table: Skip/Take.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options in order to perform Pagination.

You can move the `pagination` of the view (OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 60 ROWS ONLY) in a new stored procedure which accepts two parameters of `Skip` and `Take`. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938945/7855321)

Or, you can use a simple IQueryable from the View and then use `Skip()` , `Take()` linq methods. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874717/7855321)

I personally prefer the **first approach** while working on large tables